# How did they capture all of the Symbiotes in the Venom movie?

Tags: marvel, venom-2018, sonys-marvel-universe

At the start of the movie, they are already in the spaceship with the Symbiotes.

So how were they able to capture the Symbiotes in the first place?

Comment: Magic and handwaving.

Answer (score 6):

---

## They wanted to be captured so it was easy to get them.

---

From an [IGN interview](https://www.inverse.com/article/49144-venom-spoilers-how-do-the-symbiotes-get-to-earth) with the VFX supervisor [Paul Franklin](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0291518/), he says:

> "*We see, at the beginning of the film, the moment when the symbiotes are collected up by a Life Foundation space probe which finds them on a comet drifting through space, approaching Earth*".

And as further said by Franklin,

> "***The symbiotes seem to actively want to be collected. Because it’s all part of their plan to come to Earth. They’re looking for planets where they can find hosts to inhabit. They’ve never really found a place where they can exist in harmony with the life forms of whatever planet they find themselves on***".

So, to answer your question, the Life Foundation space probe found a comet with lifeforms (the Symbiotes) on it. The symbiotes merely allowed the probe to capture them (and take them back to a habitable planet where they could find suitable hosts).

Comment: I watched Venom last night and I'm sure the scene described wasn't in it. The version I watched begins with the Life Foundation spaceship returning to Earth and crashing on re-entry, the fact they collected the symbiotes from a comet is mentioned later but never shown.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths yeah. i presume that this was one of the scenes that got deleted. As far as i remember, there was a supposed scene where the LF ship is leaving a planet (Klyntar obviously) full of symbiotes (and not a comet/asteroid).

Comment: Didn't either or both Venom and Riot explain they wanted to be captured later in the movie?

Comment: @Kwola-T they didn't.. but they wanted to come to Earth to "assimilate" all life.. And they cannot survive in an oxygen-rich environment without a host (as told by Dr. Skirth in movie). So its obvious they did want to be captured..